# Can somebody provide authentic description of fifty-one Shaktipeethas?

Tags: puranas, tantra, shakti, upapuranas

There are conflicting evidences regarding the fifty-one Shakti-peethas in different scriptures. The locations and descriptions available on net and youtube are full of mistakes and showing false images.

Can anybody provide their authentic locations mentioning the body parts, preferably with images,**especially of the following : Suchidesha, Mithila, Panchasagara, Gandaki, Kaalamadhava**.

Comment: Note:  Whoever casted close vote. It's not too broad. In fact it is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer regarding the 5 Shakti Pithas you have mentioned separately:

**Mithila (43rd in the list):**

> Mithilayam uma devi vamaskandhah mahodarah ||
>
> In Mithila, Devi's left shoulder fell and Bhairava is Mahodarah.

**Suchi or Anala (33):**

> Samharakhya urdhadanto devi narayani shuchau ||
>
> Upper tooth fell in Suchi and Devi is called Narayani here.

Apparently, there is no such place called Anala in India, so, the historians concluded this to be near a lake in Amhedabad (Gujarat).

**Pancha Sagarah (34):**

> Adhodanta maharudro varahi panchasagare ||
>
> In Panchasagar, Devi's lower tooth fell; Devi's name is Varahi here
>   and Bhairava is Maharudra.

**Kalamadhava (29):**

> Nitamba kalamadhave | Bhairavaschasitanhascha devi kali susiddhida ||
>
> Devi's buttocks fell in Kala Madhava; Devi is called Kali and Bhairava
>   is Asitanga.

**Gandaki or Gandaka (11):**

> Gandakyam ganda patashcha tatra siddhirnasamsayaha |
>  Tantra sa
>   gandaki chandi chakrapanistu bhairava ||
>
> In Gandaka region fell Sati's cheeks and here Siddhi is achieved
>   without doubt; Devi here is known as Ganadaki Chandi and Bhairava is
>   Chakrapani.

Note, Gandaki or Gandaka is not a place but a river in Nepal.

Source is an article in one book (Jyotish and Nakshtra) that I have. I am not sure from which scriptures it is quoting the verses given.

Comment: Yes Rickross, i hv this list. i want to know current locations:)

Comment: Oh ok @Partha .....

Comment: The book is having images of all the Shakti pithas but not mentioned the places for each one of them.. @Partha I will hv to chk another book, will update

Comment: Thats unfortunate.Are they camera photos?

Comment: Yes pics taken with camera.. @Partha

Comment: u cd pl add some from the shortlist of possible

Comment: verses are from Pithanirnaya-Tantra i think

Comment: Yes sure , but for that I need to chk another book .. will do that and update @Partha

Comment: Yes could be from Pithanirnaya Tantra @Partha

Comment: @Partha For Mithila, Gandaki and Suchi I can give the present day locations for others I can't